# How to get two digits date and time in android?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

My requirement is when click the button then open date picker dialog and select the date then click ok button , that selected date will visible in edit text. But i want to display that date have "01-01-14" format instead of 1-1-14. please check my code snippet
'

```
private String setdate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Process to get Current Date
        int fYear, fMonth, fDay;
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        fYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        fMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        fDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(RemindMeDetails.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        try{
                            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                            String cdate = formatter.format(new Date());
                            Date Cdate = formatter.parse(cdate);

                            String date=(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year).toString();

                            /*String date=(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year).toString();*/
                            Date dateD = formatter.parse(date); 

                            if (Cdate.compareTo(dateD)<=0){
                                onetime_edit_date.setText(date);

                            }                           
                            else{
                                showmessage("Alert", "date is not lower than current Date");
                            }

                        }catch (ParseException e1){
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }                       
                    }
                }, fYear, fMonth, fDay );
        dpd.show();
        return cmn_date;        
}
```

'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting a date with the values received from onDateSetter. Hope this helps

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    try{
                       Date date = new Date(year+1900, monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
                       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
                       String cdate = formatter.format(date);
                      }catch (ParseException e1){
                          e1.printStackTrace(); } 
  }
  return cdate;
}
```

Comment: but in my code have two dates, one is current date another one is selected date. So tou are talking abot which date???

Comment: Venki, I am referring the date which was selected from the date picker

Comment: Why add 1900 to the year?

Answer (score 3):

All you need is

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year + 1900, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
String cdate = formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

and then set it with

```
onetime_edit_date.setText(cdate);
```

You don't need the rest of your code that manipulates the strings.

The only thing to be careful of is that the month field is 0-based: January is represented by zero. So depending on where your `monthOfYear` argument is coming from, you might need to subtract 1.

Note the `yy` rather than your `yyyy` in the format string, to get a two-digit year.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar instance to store the year, month and day values

```
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
```

And then use SimpleDateFormat to format the String output

```
String out=formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: already i used this snippet in my code... my problem is date is entered in 1 digit, i want 01 instead of 1 like 01-01-2015  instead of 1-1-2015

Comment: firstly, I think you should use Calendar class to compare date instead of using String to compare. And in your example, you used
    String date=(dayOfMonth + "-"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" +year).toString();

to create that "date" String but not Calendar, which caused you to have 1-1-2015 in "date" variable